Cannot run: dotnet ef migrations on .NET version 8.0.7
I am trying to run an Entity Framework migration using the latest version of .Net (8.0.7):
dotnet ef migrations add UpdateJob

but I get this error:
You must install .NET to run this application.

App: /home/radu/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-ef
Architecture: x64
App host version: 8.0.7
.NET location: Not found

Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

Download the .NET runtime:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=linux-x64&os=ubuntu.22.04&apphost_version=8.0.7


Please note that I have installed dotnet-ef:
Tool 'dotnet-ef' was reinstalled with the stable version (version '8.0.7').

Here is my dotnet info:
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.303
 Commit:            29ab8e3268
 Workload version:  8.0.300-manifests.c915c39d
 MSBuild version:   17.10.4+10fbfbf2e

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  22.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         linux-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/

.NET workloads installed:
There are no installed workloads to display.

Host:
  Version:      8.0.7
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       2aade6beb0

.NET SDKs installed:
  8.0.303 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.7 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.7 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download



Did you added nuget microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools package?

Yes this package was added.

if you run add-migration in nuget package manager console does't that works?

In addition, run these dotnet --version, dotnet --list-sdks and dotnet --list-runtimes command and check if you have the correct sdk and runtime installed like this

dotnet --version: 8.0.303, dotnet --list-sdks: 8.0.303, dotnet --list-runtimes: 8.0.7

I faced the same issue during migration, where the migration process failed with the following error:
'You must install or update .NET to run this application.'
After troubleshooting, I discovered that the root cause was the version of the .NET SDK being used, which was incompatible with the current setup. Once I updated Visual Studio, it automatically resolved the SDK version conflict, and the migration issue was successfully fixed. The update ensured that the correct .NET SDK version was applied, allowing the process to run smoothly.


